# file_get_contents on a page that requires login

Tags: php, authentication, file-get-contents

suppose the page that I want to get data from requires login...how can I use file_get_contents to acquire the data on that page?

Comment: curl comes to mind, and of course you have permission to do this from the site owner

Comment: Probably you will need to send a POST request using file_get_contents + stream_context_create to send your login credentials, fetch the sent cookies from $http_response_header and use anohter file_get_contents + stream_context_create to access the target page with this cookie.

Comment: If you need to aquire a login cookie, then `get_headers()` might be a better first step. But you could likely simplify things if you use Zend_Http or PEARs Http_Request2 with support for cookiejars.

Comment: @mario: Though `get_headers` doesn't accept a stream context. You would need to set a default context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use curl to get the data you want.

```
    $url        = "http://site.com/url-to-post-data-to";
$postfields = "var1=data&var2=data";
$password   = "password"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $password);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

CURL would be a better way to do this, but if you have to use file_get_contents, then to use any "advanced" http options like user/password stuff, you have to create a stream context first. THere's a sample on the PHP [docs page here](http://php.net/file_get_contents), looke for Example #4.